# How to bind nullable property to gridview databind()?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I take startdate as nullable property for startdate variable.

```
private DateTime? _StartDate;

    public DateTime? StartDate
    {
        get { return _StartDate; }
        set { _StartDate = value; }
    }
```

I have gridview with data of employee.

Among all the columns startdate column is not visible when I bind the data with gridview  when there is no data into startdate column in table.

Comment: I try to explain it as much as possible.

Comment: Should `StartDate` display when there is a value?

Comment: yes, it is displayed when it has value...

Answer (score 1):

When you set up binding you can define what should be displayed when the value is null using `TargetNullValue` property. See an example:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Price, TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:String.Empty}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

in gridview if the value is null then its automatically fill as a no value for that column.

Comment: But, that column is not visible. that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using AutoGenerate columns=true for your scenario, in such cases the GridView fails to display such an Nullable field owing due to the `IsBindbleType` type failing which doesn't account for nullable types. [Read this](http://vaultofthoughts.net/IsBindableTypeMysteryMethod.aspx)

I think you would need to go for Bound Fields for this to work.

Comment: I have set is as autogenerate columns = false but. nothing happened. Thanks for your reply.. but not helped me.

Comment: <asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="false">                    </asp:GridView>

Comment: I mean the columns for displaying,how are they set